# AME (Average Marginal Effect) for lme4::glmer using margins::margins command

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, marginal-effect

I am running a logistic mixed model regression using 
`lme4::glmer`
Command.

I wanted to report AME (average marginal effect for my coefficients). I used the following command (lme4 package's manual says it works for `glmer` so why not use that?):
`margins::margins`

I have seen threads of questions and answers with similar topics that suggest:
`ggeffects::ggpredict`

My problem is that `ggpredict` does not provide AMEs. It just gives me predictions for 50 levels of my independent variable.

Which one should I use and why? lme4 package's manual says it workd for `glmer` so why not use that? Why do people use and suggest `ggeffects` instead?

Comment: Define your AME in terms of distribution parameters ore function of distribution parameters, then it is not hard to get the estimate of AME given you can get the estimate of parameters through logistic regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also obtain coefficients from a generalized linear mixed model that have the desired marginal interpretation. These coefficients are provided by function `marginal_coefs()` of the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. For an example, check [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#marginalized-coefficients).

Comment: it is not working: `Error in UseMethod("marginal_coefs") : 
  no applicable method for 'marginal_coefs' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod') `

Comment: You have to fit the model using the `mixed_model()` function of the **GLMMadaptive** package.